# meaning of "the spare change of myself that no one yet had pocketed"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm reading *The Muse* by Jessie Burton. The protagonist / narrator is a girl from the Republic of Trinidad and Tobago who came to work in London. She describes herself as follows:

> Cynth once told me that I looked better in profile, and I said that
>   made me sound like I was a coin. But now it makes me wonder about my
>   two sides, the arch impression I probably gave Pamela, **the spare
>   change of myself that no one yet had pocketed**. The truth was, I felt
>   so prim before a girl like Pamela. She knew no other blacks, she told
>   me on the Thursday of that first week. When I replied that I hadn’t
>   known any either by that name till I came here, she looked completely
>   blank.

I don't understand what she means by "the spare change of myself that no one yet had pocketed". Does this mean that she thinks she's worthless? Or quite the opposite, she thinks she has her value but no one has seen it? Can anybody help me understand the idea of this sentence?

Comment: I think, **pocketed** here means **earned** and I roughly agree with your second interpretation. Lets wait for the native.

Comment: Speaking as a native, it seems an elegant phrase, but somewhat lacking in clarity of meaning, on its own or in context. Clues are **arch**: showing that you think it is amusing that you know more about something than someone else does,  and **prim**: very formal and correct in behaviour and easily shocked by anything rude.

Comment: We're not supposed to get into literary interpretation here. We can help with syntax and grammar and unusual usages, but we can't stray into interpretation.  The deeper implications of the verb "pocketed" and the comparison to "spare change"  will have to remain an open question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a literary interpretation that goes well beyond a question about the literal meaning of a phrase.